# Problem to make a cluster with laravel and docker swarm using laradock

Tags: laravel, cluster-computing, docker-swarm, docker-machine, laradock

I recently started with docker and I have been following this steps to make a cluster with laradock
https://github.com/jarnovanleeuwen/laravel-dock

first I create with docker-machine 2 nodes, one manager and the other a worker
then with this comand I set the manager node as the leader

```
docker swarm init --advertise-addr 192.168.99.100
```

I add the other node as a worker with

```
docker swarm join
```

After I access the manager node with docker-machine ssh manager and create a service

```
docker service create --name registry --publish published=5000,target=5000 registry:2
```

I leave the virtual machine with exit and cd into the folder laravel-dock, then I up the containers to create the images with

```
./dock up
```

then I set it down

```
./dock down
```

I build the image with

```
./dock build
```

Then i push it into the service I created with

```
./dock push

The push refers to repository [192.168.99.100:5000/registry]
Get https://192.168.99.100:5000/v2/: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

With this I try to deploy the stack with

```
./dock deploy

Are you sure you want to deploy [192.168.99.100:5000/registry:web] to [docker@192.168.99.100]? (y/N) y

Uploading deployment configuration...The authenticity of host '192.168.99.100 (192.168.99.100)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:r1F+7kuet+grlysNruBECAmYpRVVlvORYhAR4ipNFco.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.99.100' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
docker@192.168.99.100's password: 
docker@192.168.99.100's password: 
OK
docker@192.168.99.100's password: 
./dock-swarm: line 4: .env: No such file or directory
```

it request the password for the machine that is "tcuser" and come with this error ".env: No such file or directory", so I manually copy the .env to this folder created in the manager node with

```
docker-machine scp -r .env manager:/home/docker/laraveldock
```

I try to deploy again and have this error

```
sudo ./dock deploy


Are you sure you want to deploy [192.168.99.100:5000/registry:web] to [docker@192.168.99.100]? (y/N) y

Uploading deployment configuration...docker@192.168.99.100's password: 
docker@192.168.99.100's password: 
OK
docker@192.168.99.100's password: 
Top-level object must be a mapping
```

And at this point I have stuck with this error, am I doing something wrong in this steps? also here is the configurations

.env

```
APP_ID=laraveldock
DEPLOY_SERVER=docker@192.168.99.100
DOCKER_REPOSITORY=192.168.99.100:5000/registry:web

REGISTRY=localhost:5000
REGISTRY_USER=docker
REGISTRY_PASSWORD=tcuser

APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:25q1JJ78zFzeGYOBIyIndCmuSJBOCaezyW2utE7hE3Y=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_DATABASE=laraveldock
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=secret

REDIS_PASSWORD=rediz

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
DB_DATABASE=laraveldock
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=secret

REDIS_PASSWORD=rediz

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

# Volumes
volumes:
  mysql:
    driver: local
  redis:
    driver: local

services:

  # Apache + PHP
  app:

    environment:
      - CONTAINER_ROLE=app
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_PORT=3306
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
      - REDIS_PORT=6379
    env_file: ../.env
    ports:
      - "80:80"

  # Scheduler
  scheduler:
    user: webdev
    environment:
      - CONTAINER_ROLE=scheduler
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_PORT=3306
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
      - REDIS_PORT=6379
    env_file: ../.env

  # Queue worker
  queue:
    user: webdev
    environment:
      - CONTAINER_ROLE=queue
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_PORT=3306
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
      - REDIS_PORT=6379
    env_file: ../.env

  # MySQL
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: ["--character-set-server=utf8mb4", "--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci"]
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_DATABASE}
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql/

  # Redis
  redis:
    image: redis:5.0
    command: ["redis-server", "--appendonly", "yes", "--requirepass", "${REDIS_PASSWORD}"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent an hour on this bug. In my case problem was caused by missing docker-compose on remote server.